# A triple definite integral from Cartesian coordinates to Spherical coordinates. Help!

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

I am trying to <s>solve</s> evaluate this triple definite integral. The integral is given below.

$$
\Lambda =\int_0^3\int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{1+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} \, dz\,dy\,dx
$$

I know that this problem has to be done in spherical coordinates, since we have a triple integral, and we have the following relationship :

$$
x^2+y^2+z^2
$$

and I know that this equals to:

$$
\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
$$

I know that for spherical coordinates my x,y,z variables have the following form:

$$
x = \rho\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)
\\
y = \rho\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)
\\
z = \rho\cos(\phi)
$$

Once I make the substitutions my integral expression gets really complicated, and I have no idea how to proceed from there. Could anybody post a step by step solution to this triple definite integral?And also showing how the change of variables are done within the coordinates and the integral. I do believe that using spherical coordinates for this problem is the best way to <s>solve</s> evaluate this triple integral. Thank You!

Comment: Did you forget the jacobian :)

Comment: @IntegrateThis o yes , you are right, when changing variables from Cartesian to spherical, i should always multiple the integrand by the determinant of the jacobian matrix.

Comment: The integrand is $\frac {p^3} { 1+ p^4} sin \phi$

Comment: becomes $ln |u|$, what is confusing you? The expression in $u$ have no theta or phi values, you can treat each component separately.

Comment: @IntegrateThis Ok I get this, but I am confused on how you got the upper bounds for the integrational limits.

Comment: @IntegrateThis This is the case since the integration limits are are solved for z in the first one and y in the second one , right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to deal the sphere in the first octant. so $\theta$ varies from $o$ to $\pi/2$, $\rho$ from $0$ to $3$, $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$.
$$
\Lambda =\int_0^3\int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{1+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} \, dz \, dy \, dx$$

$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta\int_{0}^{\phi=\pi/2}\sin(\phi) \,  d\phi \int_0^{\rho=3} \frac{{\rho^3}}{1+(\rho)^4} \, d\rho \, d\phi 
$$
Here you can integrate.

Comment: If you find any type error, please let me know.

Comment: I think that $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi/2$

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Could you include how you changed yours integrational limits in terms of the spherical coordinates variables.  Like how did you get 0 to p = 3 and 0 to pi/2 and 0 to pi ?

Comment: $z $ varies from 0 to the sphere. right? so $\phi$ varies from $0$ to $\pi/2$

Comment: y varies from $0$ to projection circle. Right?. so $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $pi$($\because$ we deal the semi circle.

Comment: do you get the point???

Comment: its a quarter of a circle, it would be a semi circle if y varied from - sqrt(x^2+y^2) to sqrt (x^2+y^2)

Comment: no. that would be a full circle. please draw and verify.

Comment: x goes from 0 to -3, not from -3 to 3. I am sure I am right

Comment: do you get the point?

Comment: It is only positive values of both x and y, how could that be a semi circle :)

Comment: No, $\rho$ is a positive quantity. please study the domain of, $\rho,\phi,\theta$ thorougly.

Comment: Theta varies from 0 to pi/2. Gotta go, but draw the picture.

Comment: yes. yes.thank you

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan could you pleaes edit your answer to include how you changed the variables, and how you got the integrational limits of the 3 integrals from spherical coordinates ?

Comment: Now it is clear no?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan now is better, if i have further questions, i will ask you again. thank

Comment: ok.did you integrate it?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan I am doing it right now, i will post my answer once i finish

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan  I got ln(82)*pi/2  . Is this correct ?

Comment: No. In denomenator, must be 8. check again.

Answer (score 1):

You want to integrate a rotationally symmetric function over an eighth of a ball of radius $3$. Partition this ball onionlike in spherical shells of area ${1\over8}\cdot 4\pi r^2$ and thickness $dr$. In this way you obtain
$$\Lambda={\pi\over8}\int_0^3{r\over 1+r^4}\>4r^2\>dr={\pi\over8}\>\log(1+r^4)\biggr|_0^3={\pi\over8}\log 82$$
Doing it all the way in terms of spherical coordinates involves computing the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation.